# Sharing external C++ headers among developers

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 2012, C++ project.

My project has a dependency to external library (includes its headers). Library is large and should not be stored in source-controlled repository itself. Each developer may keep the library sources in different locations (Dev1 will keep it on C:\libs, Dev2 somewhere else).

Is there a way to keep the dependency in the project, but yet to avoid committing VC++ Project file with my own path to remote repository? I was thinking about adding to "Include" directories environment variable that each developer would have to set properly on their machines, but maybe there are some better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you only include header files, you can use

`#include <header>`

instead of

`#include "header.h"`

That way, the compiler will take the header from the standard include path, eg VS2012/VC/include.

Other developers may have different standard paths.

For further information see:

http://www2.informatik.uni-halle.de/lehre/c/c_includ.html